# Form input from another tab

Tags: php, javascript, html

Page A has a form with various fields such as name, address, and so on.  On page B I have a form that has already been filled out with this information.  I would like to send the data from page B to page A.  The catch is, I can't edit the code on page A, so I can't set it up to look for changes, and I can't put an object on page A to call a function and fill out the form.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you can't touch page A, then no, you can't do this in any permanent way. Is this for personal use? You can use the developer console / firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript and an Iframe! This would require having a page C that would obtain info from page B and then enter the info into page A where Page A would merely be displayed in page C via an Iframe

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that seems to have worked.  I need to disable the browsers same origin policy to write to the form in the iframe but since the computer I'll be doing that on is used for only very minimal web browsing it should be fine.

Comment: mind accepting the answer? I have done this exact same thing before and it works great! best of luck. Also if both pages are on the same domain you woulnt need to disable the browser security.